# running sqlldr control files in UNIX

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I have a question. I have this control files that works fine when I run it from a windows client. However when I run it directly in Linux, it shows load complete but when I look at my oracle data, there is NO DATA and there are even bad records. Below is my control file that works well in windows but fails in Linux.
**NOTE: The control file works if I remove the string or date converted fields**

**Control file**

```
load data   
infile 'HOME/INPUT/FILEA.dat'  
badfile 'HOME/BAD/FILEA.bad'  
discardfile 'HOME/DIS/FILEA.dsc'  
truncate    
into table TEST  
fields terminated by '|'   
trailing nullcols  
( ABCcode  CHAR(11),    
ABCID  CHAR(6),    
ABC_SEQNO  "to_number(:ABC_SEQNO,'999999')",    
PSNO  "to_number(:PSNO,'99999999999.999')",    
ABDF  CHAR(1),    
ABCFI  CHAR(1),    
ABC_DATE NULLIF ABC_DATE="00000000" "to_date(:ABC_DATE, 'YYYYMMDD')",    
XZY_date NULLIF XZY_date="00000000" "to_date(:XZY_date, 'YYYYMMDD')",    
DESC  CHAR(1))
```

Any help or ideas to get this code to run in Linux will be appreciated

**Notes about the logfile: The logfile had the following

ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1

ORA-12899: value too large for column "ABCschema"."TEST"."ABC_DATE" (actual: 9, maximum: 8)

 Also, the date conversion had the following

 NULL if ABC_DATE = 0X3030303030303030(character '00000000')
    SQL string for column : "to_date(:ABC_DATE, 'YYYYMMDD')"**

Comment: Did you try generating the log file? If yes, what were the errors? If not, why?

Comment: I did and I just updated my post to reflect the messages I got from the log file

Comment: Yes, I actually moved the data from windows to Linux

Comment: Hmm, actually, don't think it is that... what data type is `TEST.ABC_DATE` - looks like a `VARCHAR2` from the error, not a `DATE`? And is this the same DB you were loading to from Windows? It looks like you're doing an implicit conversion of that formatted date back to a string for insertion, which is never good; the error might match an `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` of `DD-MON-RR` for example. Can you check what format `sysdate` is given if you do a plain `select sysdate from dual` from SQL*Plus on both boxes? Sample data, and table definition, might help too.

Comment: sysdate is in DD-MON-RR. The date from the data is a varchar but had to be converted to a date format of yyyymmdd.

Comment: I understand that the file has `YYYYMMDD` and you're converting it to a date; but I'm sure the `ABC_DATE` column in your `TEST` table is actually `VARCHAR2(8)`. With a valid input string like `20140218` and the NLS_DATE_FORMAT you showed, you would get error `ORA-12899: value too large for column ... (actual: 9, maximum: 8)`. I've just tested and verified it.

Comment: The ABC_DATE column in test is actually a DATE data type but the data containing the ABC_DATE column is in a character format 20140218. I had to use To_date to convert it to a date format in order for it to load successfully into the TEST table (using a windows platform). If I take out the To_date conversion and change the ABC_DATE to varchar2, it works fine but I don't want to go about changing the whole date types to VARCHAR2 for every column attribute in TEST

Comment: `dos2unix FileCreatedOnWidowsToBeUsedonLinux`. Good luck.

Comment: The error you show is from the table column being a string. If you're switching the table definition, please show what error(s) you get when it's a definitely a date.

Comment: Silly me! I just realized that the proper data types were not reflected on the table columns. I fixed it and everything seems to be fine. Thanks Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `TEST` table has the `ABC_DATE` column defined as `VARCHAR2(8)`, not as a `DATE`.

If I create a table as:

```
create table test (
  ABCcode VARCHAR2(11),
  ABCID VARCHAR2(6),
  ABC_SEQNO NUMBER,
  PSNO NUMBER,
  ABDF VARCHAR2(1),
  ABCFI VARCHAR2(1),
  ABC_DATE DATE,
  XZY_date DATE,
  "DESC" VARCHAR2(1)
);
```

and have a data file with:

```
A|B|1|2.3|C|D|20140217|20140218|E
```

then it loads fine. If I recreate the table as:

```
create table test (
  ABCcode VARCHAR2(11),
  ABCID VARCHAR2(6),
  ABC_SEQNO NUMBER,
  PSNO NUMBER,
  ABDF VARCHAR2(1),
  ABCFI VARCHAR2(1),
  ABC_DATE VARCHAR2(8),
  XZY_date DATE,
  "DESC" VARCHAR2(1)
);
```

... then the same control file and data file now give me:

```
Record 1: Rejected - Error on table TEST, column ABC_DATE.
ORA-12899: value too large for column "<schema>"."TEST"."ABC_DATE" (actual: 9, maximum: 8)
```

You are converting the string value to a date, but then you're doing an implicit conversion back to a string when it actually inserts the data into the `VARCHAR2` column. When it does that it's using your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` settings, and the error I got was from having that set to `DD-MON-RR`.

You have three options really. Either modify your table to have actual `DATE` columns; or change the control file so it just inserts the plain text value and doesn't do the date conversion at all; or massage your environment so the conversion back to a string gets the format you want the string to be.

Only the first one is really sensible - if it's a date value, always store it as a `DATE`, never as a string.

The `0X30...` thing isn't a problem, that's just showing the internal representation it's using.

Comment: Quick question, are you loading it directly from Linux or from a Windows environment

Comment: @user2008558 - Linux. But this is about your database and table, and your Db environment, not the operating system.

Comment: Thanks Alex. You are absolutely right. I just realized that the data attributes were modified to VARCHAR2. Now the control file works Thanks for you help.